# Insert into and select from with one ready value

Tags: php, mysql

What I want to do here is to insert some values to a table but that value come from another table.

However, there are some value which is ready to post.

```
  $reference_no = $_POST ['reference_no']
  $location_id = $_SESSION ['location_id']

  INSERT INTO infistall_location_stock_collect_update (package, quantity, location_id)
      SELECT product_id, quantity, '...'
      FROM orders_history
      WHERE reference_no = '$reference_no'
```

How to put the $location_id in the SELECT query?

Thanks

Comment: How did you do it with `$reference_no`? In what way is that way unsuitable for `$location_id`?

Comment: Because as far as I know the thing with SELECT is the column name, not the value in the column. Different with WHERE clause.

Comment: Then the answer by fortune must come as a surprise to you :)

Comment: But also the location_id is not belong to orders_history table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO infistall_location_stock_collect_update (package, quantity, location_id)
SELECT product_id, quantity, '$location_id'
FROM orders_history
WHERE reference_no = '$reference_no'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the column

```
$reference_no = $_POST ['reference_no']
$location_id = $_SESSION ['location_id']

INSERT INTO infistall_location_stock_collect_update (package, quantity, location_id)
  SELECT product_id, quantity, '(".$location_id.")' as location_id
  FROM orders_history
  WHERE reference_no = '$reference_no'
```

Happy Coding ..